# Server response is empty or blank using app on Windows 8.1

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a strange situation with an application. I wrote it using Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 7 laptop. It sends server requests via XML strings and receives responses from the server. In the debug environment it works perfectly. I compiled and deployed the app, installed on the Windows 7 laptop and it works perfectly.

When I install the application on Windows tablet 8.1, I get empty responses from the server.  The error is root element missing, but I know what is generating that error, there is no XML response.

Is there something different about Windows 8.1 that would cause the server responses not to show?  I'm also using .net 4.5.

The application will send a string to the server and I do show that I'm logged in. I can run SQL queries against the server, but when I send XML data, the response is always blank

Here is my code:

```
Public Function sendCommand(command As String) As String
        Try
            bw = New EndianBinaryWriter(New BigEndianBitConverter(), tcS)
            'Dim encoding As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
            Dim encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(True)
            Dim bytes As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(command)
            bw.Write(bytes.Length)
            bw.Write(bytes)

            bw.Flush()
            br = New EndianBinaryReader(New BigEndianBitConverter(), tcS)
            Dim i As Integer = br.ReadInt32()

            Dim bytess As Byte() = New Byte(i - 1) {}
            br.Read(bytess, 0, i)
            Dim response As String = encoding.GetString(bytess, 0, i)
            br.Close()
            MsgBox(response)
            MsgBox(command)
            Return response


        Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
            Return ""
        End Try
    End Function
```

This is what works on Windows 7 and returns empty on Windows 8.

If you need any other information I will happily upload.

Comment: So, no code, no context, not anything concrete to help anyone help you...

Comment: sorry, here is my code below...

Comment: I put msgboxes in there so I can see the value of the XML string I'm sending and the value of the returned response...just for testing at this point in code.

Comment: so why are you messing with endian binary converters when just sending a string? I've been sending strings across the wire for years, and never had to do this...

Comment: @Jeremy - the database I'm connecting to is a Firebird Database and the dev team there stated that communicating required Endian.  I just went with that....I haven't tried anything else, but again, in a Windows 7 environment, nothing is wrong, only on a Windows 8.1 tablet

Comment: and yet another detail you neglected to tell. we are not psychic.

Comment: @Jeremy - I'm sorry, I'm new to asking questions and didn't know what to say about my environment.  I just knew with the code I have, I'm able to send and receive XML and SQL data just fine in a Windows 7 environment and that there must be something different about Windows 8.1 that won't allow receiving.